# Can mysql 5.7 recognize mysqldump file from 5.1?

Tags: mysql

we know the supported logical upgrade method is:
5.1-5.5,
5.5-5.6,
5.6-5.7.
In each step, we mysqldump, then we need 3times.
If I mysqldump from 5.1, then install mysql5.7, we need 1 time mysqldump.
Can mysql 5.7 recognize  mysqldump file from 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the differences that MySQL 5.7 offer compared to the older versions and see if it affects anything but considering how large of a jump it is, I find it hard it would "just work." In short, most likely not. Your best bet is to take your data in MySQL 5.1, upgrade it to 5.7 so your schema inherits all the changes that may have happened, and then make a new `mysqldump` of that.

Related sources:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123154/migrating-upgrading-a-mysql-5-1-schema-to-mysql-5-7-schema

[Upgrading directly from MySQL 5.0 to 5.7](http://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-directly-from-mysql-5-0-to-5-7-with-mysqldump/)